How do I access and interact with the outputs of a slack SelectSpreadsheetRow workflow step?
I'm working on a slack application that, among other things, reads and writes data from a google sheet. I have added a step to the workflow to pull the row I want from a spreadsheet here:
MyWorkflow.addStep(
  Connectors.GoogleSheets.functions.SelectSpreadsheetRow,
  {
    spreadsheet_id: "MYGOOGLESHEET",
    sheet_title: "SHEETTOSEARCH",
    column_name: "COLUMNTOSEARCH",
    // An item from earlier in the workflow
    cell_value: inputForm.outputs.fields.recipient,
    google_access_token: { credential_source: "END_USER" },
  },
);

As it stands, this code correctly executes and "finds" the match, but once I have it I cannot for the life of me find any way to actually interact with the outputs of this step.
I have checked the documentation for the workflow item here and it tells me that the values ARE outputs of the step, but nothing in the slack app documentation tells me how I can actually access and use those outputs.
For things like forms I'm able to use
formName.outputs.fields.MYFIELD

but when I attempt to set my sheet selector to a const and use its outputs I get junk
console.log(sheetSelector.outputs.column_values)

The above outputs: {"column_values":"{{steps.3.column_values}}
Again, the main issue is reading the output of this workflow step, and USING the column_values that I find.
